# FInd whether a word document is open

Tags: ms-word

I am using VBSCRIPT to open a  a MS Word document. I want to know if it is already open (even if not active) and if so avoid opening it again. There's no use just checking for Winword - the user may have other word documents open.

I tried `tasklist /V /FI "IMAGENAME eq WINWORD.EXE"` but this only returns the name of the Document (WindowTitle) of the Word Window currently active.

I have also looked at

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process")
```

but this does not give any useful info.

I really want a list of applications like in the Task Manager but which would show me all open Word documents.

Answer (score 0):

Does GetObject not suit?

```
 Set doc = GetObject("Z:\Docs\Doc.doc")
 doc.Application.Visible = True
```

If the document is already open, it will hijack it. If it is closed, it will open it in a new Word instance.

Comment: @ANTHONYGINSBERG Your tag says MS Word. Do you wish to determine of a file of any type is open? If so, it would be best to adjust your tags and question.